# Google Cloud connected device using Globalsign R2 root certificate

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, gcloud

We have some ethernet devices (iot project) communicating with our cloud based servers. Connection goes over SSL.

The device is using Global Sign R2 as Root CA. After google managed SSL certificates got updated few days ago, it felt out of chain of trust and the device cannot connect anymore.

Is there anything we can do on the backend side to allow the device to connect? Any source of SSL certificate with R2 in chain? I know it will expire soon, but we need to have it running just temporarily. Once the device connects, we will be able to upload new certficiates, but now it's dead. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the GlobalSign R2 certificate here:

[Google Trust Services Repository](https://pki.goog/repository/)

Comment: The device is using this certificate as Certificate Authority Root, I need to get an SSL certificate which can be validated using this root ca.

Comment: @Itworky Your comment/question is confusing. 1) Root certificates are trusted. There is no other certificate to verify them. 2) If you mean a certificate signed by the root or an intermediary, the root/intermediary certificates validate that certificate. 3) If you mean you want a new certificate that can be validated, you must go to the source and have a certificate request signed.  This link had details about type and validation: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/verifying-credentials Look up how you obtained the original certificate.

Comment: It is indeed. The problem is that Google changed R2 based root to R1 at the endpoint used by iot device. We knew this is gonna happen, but did not expect it to happen at this moment. Turns out, with Google Managed certificates - they can change roots at any time. The devices which are using the backend secured by such Google Managed SSL need to expect any root currently supported by Google. Just for future generations - if you use Google Managed certificates at backend, all IOT devices need to have a fallback in case they change. Wonder how many old iOT device stop working soon...